# python UUID based on email

Tags: python, email, uuid

How do I generate UUID based on email ids ?

I have [read](http://docs.python.org/library/uuid.html) the docs.

I prefer to use the UUID module.

Answer (score 7):

Without knowing exactly what the namespace thing is about, I'd try this:

```
>> import uuid
>> mail = "foo@bar.example"
>> uuid.uuid5(uuid.NAMESPACE_URL, mail)
UUID('45348e31-1ca5-57f3-ad95-cb80bf6ad145')
```

If all you need is a unique hash you can also use the `hashlib` module.

```
>> import hashlib
>> m = hashlib.sha1()
>> m.update(mail)
>> m.hexdigest()
'edb13b9a276142c6dcb93534a21f497fec4b93f8'
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to generate "version 3 UUID / UUID3" OR "version 5 UUID / UUID5" to solve your problem.

A version 3 UUID is created using the DNS namespace.

```
>> import uuid
>> uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS
>> UUID('6ba7b810-9dad-11d1-80b4-00c04fd430c8')
>> uuid.uuid3(uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS, 'YOU EMAIL ID')
>> UUID('3d813cbb-47fb-32ba-91df-831e1593ac29')
```

UUID5 can be generated similarly..

And you can also use "NAMESPACE_URL" to generate UUID3 or UUID5.

#### (uuid.NAMESPACE_URL)

Comment: While using **NAMESPACE_DNS** shouldn't the name be a URL like `google.com` rather than `me@google.com`

Comment: @Jibin I think so as well. And for `NAMESPACE_URL` you should IMHO prepend `mailto:`.

Comment: Commenting after 10 years: Either of `NAMESPACE_URL` and `NAMESPACE_DNS` seems to hashes any given Email address given in the `name` argument... and it _does produce_ a valid, unique, and reproducible hash (with either uuid3 or uuid5).  Practically, I didn't face any issue there.  So, why shouldn't an Email be hashed that way without prepending it with `mailto:`-- any specific reason ?

Answer (score 0):

As others have told you, you have to use uuid3 or uuid5. (Which one, it doesn't really matter if you don't care about cryptography. I'll use uuid3 in this example.) Now you have to decide on a namespace.

DNS doesn't make sense, since it only accepts FQDNs, which email address surely is not. X.500 can theoretically be used if you are in LDAP, but it's still more complicated than necessary. OID tree, as far as I know, doesn't have an arc for emails - and rightly so, since they are trying to build a *permanent* registry, and email address are not really permanent.

So, that leaves URIs. Are email addresses URIs? Fortunately, yes. [Formally, it's for URLs only, but fortunately, email addresses are URLs, too.:] URIs have a syntax described in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Generic_syntax). So you have to find a scheme, and then fit your data into it. IANA gives you [a list of schemes](http://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.xhtml), where you can find "mailto" as "Electronic mail address" "Permanent" scheme. Seems like exactly what we want.

You also get the link to the RFC, in this case [RFC 6068](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068), which tells you how exactly you should format your email address. The possible problem is that you speak about "email id", that could possibly mean just the "local-part" of it (the "username" as it's usually called). Of course, that won't do, since it isn't unique globally.

[The only way you could make it work is to somehow restrict the namespace to your mail server. You *can* do it with MX records and DNS, but much simpler is to just code the domain into the whole email address.]

```
def email_uuid(email_id, domain='your.domain.example.com'):
    from uuid import uuid3, NAMESPACE_URL
    if '@' not in email_id:
        email_id += '@' + domain
    return uuid3(NAMESPACE_URL, 'mailto:' + email_id)
```